# Knob rotation gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to create a gesture recognizer able to detect the rotation of 4 fingers (similar when you rotate a volume knob). 
The main idea was to create a subclass of UIRotateGestureRecognizer and override its method. In the `-touchesBegan` I detect the number of touches, if the number is lower than 4 the state of the gesture is fail. 
 After that I pass the location point to an algorithm that find the diameter of a convex hull. If you think about it, your fingers are the vertices and I just need to find the two vertices with the max distance. Obtained these two points I reference them as ivar and I pass them to the superclass as it is a simple rotation with just two fingers.
It doesn't work:

1. the detection of the touches seems pretty hard
2. very rarely the `-touchesHasMoved` is called
3. when its called it hangs the most of time

Can someone help me?

Here is the code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (touches.count<4) {
        //FAIL
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
        return;
    }

    //Find the diameter of the convex hull
    NSArray * touchesArray = [touches allObjects];
    NSMutableArray * pointsArray = @[].mutableCopy;
    for (UITouch * touch in touchesArray) {
        [pointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[touch locationInView:touch.view]]];
    }
    DiameterType convexHullDiameter = getDiameterFromPoints(pointsArray);
    CGPoint firstPoint =  convexHullDiameter.firstPoint;
    CGPoint secondPoint = convexHullDiameter.secondPoint;
    for (UITouch * touch in touchesArray) {
        if (CGPointEqualToPoint([touch locationInView:touch.view], firstPoint) ) {
            self.fistTouch = touch;
        }
        else if (CGPointEqualToPoint([touch locationInView:touch.view], secondPoint)){
            self.secondTouch = touch;
        }
    }
    //Calculating the rotation center as a mid point between the diameter vertices
    CGPoint rotationCenter = (CGPoint) {
        .x = (convexHullDiameter.firstPoint.x + convexHullDiameter.secondPoint.x)/2,
        .y = (convexHullDiameter.firstPoint.y + convexHullDiameter.secondPoint.y)/2
    };
    self.rotationCenter = rotationCenter;
    //Passing touches to super as a fake rotation gesture
    NSSet * touchesSet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:self.fistTouch, self.secondTouch, nil];
    [super touchesBegan:touchesSet withEvent:event];
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (touches.count<4) {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
        return;
    }

    [super touchesMoved:[[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:self.fistTouch, self.secondTouch, nil] withEvent:event];
}

- (void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
    [super touchesCancelled:[[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:self.fistTouch, self.secondTouch, nil] withEvent:event];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
    [super touchesEnded:[[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:self.fistTouch, self.secondTouch, nil] withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Don't you can use 2 finger only and use the rotation/pitch gesture (default from ios)? I'm saing that because I use two finger to change volume level in a sound system, not 4. Probably I'll use more fingers on heavy things, like a hard tap water, p.ex.

Comment: If I use just 2 fingers it wouldn't be the same thing from user perspective.

Comment: Maybe using "[[event allTouches] anyObject];" instead of "[touches allObjects];" helps a bit, I couldn't understand what your problem is exactly though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason initial detection is hard is that all the touches may not start at the same time. touchesBegan will likely be called multiple times as separate touches land on the screen. You can use the event parameter to query all of the current touches with event.allTouches. So your current approach for triggering the gesture to fail will not work. You should not set state to fail if touches.count is < 4 but instead just return if event.allTouches.count < 4. You could use a timer to set the state to fail if the fourth touch does not happen within a certain time from the first.

touchesMoved likely has problems because the touches in the event object do not match up with those in the set that you pass to super.

Comment: Thx, all your comments and suggestions make sense

Answer (score 1):

> If you think about it, your fingers are the vertices and I just need to find the two vertices with the max distance.

I don't think this will work in practice, even if you are able to trick the `UIGestureRecognizer`.

This is how I would implement the algorithm in the 'correct' way:

1. Remember the 'old' touches.
2. When you're given 'new' touches, try to match each finger to the previous touch. If you can't, fail.
3. Compute the center of 'new' + 'old' touches.
4. For each of 4 fingers identified two steps ago, compute angle traveled in radians, approximated as

   `new(i) - old(i) divided by distance to center`
5. If any angle is too big (`> 0.5`), fail.
6. This guarantees that approximation is valid.
7. Now compute the average of 4 angles.

Congratulations, you now have the rotation angle (measured in radians).

Comment: I don't get.. center is only well defined in a circonference or symmetric objects. 4 touches on an view are only approximable as center.. and to do that you need to find the diameter and define the center as the mid point. What do you mean in the step 3?

Comment: You can always find a center-of-mass of physical system by taking an average of coordinates of its objects, in this case, `(new(1) + new(2) +... + old(4)) / 8` (do it for both x and y coordinates). This center may be not the same as in the previous event, but you can still use it to find the rotation angle.

Comment: Thanks ilya I get... center of mass of unary masses... I 'll give a try.

Answer (score 0):

I would put this in a comment if I had enough Rep.

```
[super touchesMoved:[[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:self.fistTouch, self.secondTouch, nil] withEvent:event];
```

You're using something called `fistTouch`, which doesn't sound like what you want. My guess is you want `firstTouch`.

Additionally there are possible collisions between gestures going on that may be overriding each other. Did you know there is a 4-finger zoom-out in iOS7 that is a system-wide gesture? Also, a 4-finger zoom-in during an app will close it.

Comment: Hi DrDisc, Mine it was supposed to be a trick like: ok, you need 4 fingers, but instead of writing down the logic to recognize a rotation, why don't we fake it as a 2 fingers rotation? this class is a subclass of RotationGesture that is made only with 2 fingers. Your observation about conflicting gesture is true but only iPad has 4 fingers "app exit" and you can disable it. Thanks anyway